# Control if element value is the same in entire node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is necessary an expression to control that all LIGHT_RANGE are the same in all SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM.

**This is my XML:**

```
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>  <------- First Group
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <IMMUTABLE_ID>5585</IMMUTABLE_ID>
        <LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
            <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
                <LIGHT_COLOUR>G</LIGHT_COLOUR>  <-- LIGHT_COLOUR G
                <LIGHT_RANGE>3</LIGHT_RANGE>    <-- LIGHT_RANGE 3
            </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
            <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
                <LIGHT_COLOUR>R</LIGHT_COLOUR>  <-- LIGHT_COLOUR R
                <LIGHT_RANGE>3</LIGHT_RANGE>    <-- LIGHT_RANGE 3
            </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        </LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>    
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
<SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>  <------- Second Group
    <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
        <IMMUTABLE_ID>6000</IMMUTABLE_ID>
        <LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
            <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
                <LIGHT_COLOUR>R</LIGHT_COLOUR>  <-- LIGHT_COLOUR R
                <LIGHT_RANGE>10</LIGHT_RANGE>    <-- LIGHT_RANGE 10
            </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
            <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
                <LIGHT_COLOUR>G</LIGHT_COLOUR>  <-- LIGHT_COLOUR G
                <LIGHT_RANGE>10</LIGHT_RANGE>    <-- LIGHT_RANGE 10
            </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
            <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
                <LIGHT_COLOUR>W</LIGHT_COLOUR>  <-- LIGHT_COLOUR W
                <LIGHT_RANGE>12</LIGHT_RANGE>    <-- LIGHT_RANGE 12
            </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        </LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
    </NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>    
</SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_RANGE[not(. = preceding::LIGHT_RANGE[preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF])]">

    <!-- Prendo le lettere dei colori in LIGHT_COLOUR-->
    <xsl:variable name="LCorrente" select="preceding-sibling::LIGHT_COLOUR"/>                                                                                                                           
    <xsl:variable name="LPrecedente" select="preceding::LIGHT_RANGE[1][not(contains(preceding-sibling::LIGHT_COLOUR, '-'))][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF]/preceding-sibling::LIGHT_COLOUR"/>

    <!-- Prendo i numeri di portata in LIGHT_RANGE-->
    <xsl:variable name="NCorrente" select="number(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="NPrecedente" select="number(preceding::LIGHT_RANGE[1][not(contains(preceding-sibling::LIGHT_COLOUR, '-'))][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID=$EF])"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**This is the Output:**
3 (First Group)
10 12 (Second Group) <== Is necessary another  '10' because at leat element is different.

**REQUEST:**
Is necessary an expression to control that all LIGHT_RANGE are the same in all SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM. (First Case)
In the second case you can see that there are tree element, 2 are the same 1 different. In this case if at least one s different write tree element. (Second Case)

** REQUEST OUTPUT:**
3 <== Return 3 because all element LIGHT_RANGE in this SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM are the same.

10 
10
12  <== Second group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following XSLT outputs `true` when all LIGHT_RANGE are of the same value, else `false`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/SECTION_CONTENT_LIST_ITEM">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(.//LIGHT_RANGE) = count(.//LIGHT_RANGE[. = (current()//LIGHT_RANGE)[1]])"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Lingamurthy CS, you are very help.

Comment: +1 for your nice logics. With 'generate-id' also we can do this right?.

Comment: @RudramuniTP, generate-id() produces unique id for every node it is called for and hence won't help.

Comment: Is this is correct for this input?, generate-id(.//LIGHT_RANGE)=generate-id(current()//LIGHT_RANGE).

Comment: . and current() are same in your case hence evaluating to true. Try: generate-id(.//LIGHT_RANGE)=generate-id(current()//LIGHT_RANGE[2]), which is comparing the LHS with id of second LIGHT_RANGE

Comment: I am studing your Xslt, after 30 minutes...I undertand. Very Good. :-) #Lingamurthy CS